# How to add if condition inside of useState in React

Tags: reactjs, rxjs, use-state, react-state, conditional-rendering

I want to add if condition inside of use state.
So here is my code example:

```
const [buttonName, setButtonName] = useState('Connect Wallet');

  const changeButtonName = () => {
    localStorage.getItem('address') ? setButtonName('Wallet Connected') : setButtonName('Connect Wallet');
  };
```

so I want to add changeButtonName into useState. The reason why I want to do it is as soon as the page renders I want to check if there is address in local and if there is I want to set the name of the button.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can initialize state lazily

```
const [buttonName, setButtonName] = useState(() => {
    return localStorage.getItem('address') ? 'Wallet Connected' : 'Connect Wallet'
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not correct to add conditions inside useState
Do the following thing instead.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  changeButtonName()
},[])

The empty dependency array makes sure that the function gets called on the first render
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the ternary operator directly inside

```
const [buttonName, setButtonName] = useState( localStorage.getItem('address') ?'Wallet Connected' :'Connect Wallet');
```